# how to efficiently search a structured numeric array

Tags: arrays, search

I have a virtual array of GB size which is m by n and for which higher values are to the right and towards the top. By virtual i mean that return values are provided from another program from coordinates given, but the functions on a given run are not known to the programmer. It is guaranteed that a  given number is in the array.

{Now turns out that such number is the product of two primes, and so is NP hard}

I looked at [Efficient search of sorted numerical values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934412/efficient-search-of-sorted-numerical-values)
but it doesn't have the multiple row structure i need to reflect. I tried a "spiral" approach but it sometimes takes a long time to traverse. (Looking at more than half the possible slots) Typically rows have regular gaps, but will be different for each row. Columns tend to have (different) arithmetic progression.
The rows are sorted. The left most value in a row is less than the left most value in next higher row, The right most value in a row is less than the right most value in the next higher row. See example data below.
What i have tried is to first eliminate rows which cannot hold the target value and then pick the "middle" value row of those remaining. Do a binary search on that row, then go up or down according to whether the next row is likely (guess) to have more values in range or not. The target value is likely to be randomly placed within the possible slots available. 
Here is some sample data

1008    1064    1120    1176    1232

999 1053    1107    1161    1215

988 1040    1092    1144    1196

975 1025    1075    1125    1175

960 1008    1056    1104    1152

Any ideas please?

Comment: Clarify ' higher values are to the right and towards the top".  Is A[10,0] more or less that A[0, 1]. Do value rise going right, and then up, or rise moving outward from A[0,0]

Comment: In other words, is one row distinctly smaller than the next or are the rows sorted individually but wouldn't necessarily be sorted if you concatenated them?

Comment: Correct, concatenating won't work.see edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to factorization if the target number is product of only two numbers (prime) which turns out to be the case {that wasn't clear at time of posting}.
Factorization is known to be NP hard.
An interesting sidelight on factorization and decision theory is here
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25466/factoring-as-a-decision-problem
and here
http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/is-factoring-really-in-bqp-really/